# response from ajax HttpURLConnection POST is getting encoded

Tags: ajax, httpurlconnection

I'm using the HttpURLConnection POST to get the response. Im able to get the responsecode 200 but the responseString is getting encoded as below::
���������RP�b��%+c//17�Wr
��u���v����QJ�r��-�N�9���

here is the code I'm using::

```
public static String getPOSTAJAX(String getURL,String impersonationID,String getPOSTParameters)
{

    // get Impersonation ID
    String getimpersonationID = "bearer "+impersonationID;
    String getResponseline = "";
    String getPOSTResponse = null;
    String postCookies = "sid="+impersonationID;

    try
    {
        //Open HttpURLConnection
        URL url = new URL(getURL);
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        //add request header
        if (impersonationID != null && impersonationID != " ") {
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", getimpersonationID);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", postCookies);
        }
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json,text/plain,*/*");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.94 Safari/537.36");
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(getPOSTParameters.getBytes().length));
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        //send the POSt Request
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        DataOutputStream writeRequest = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        writeRequest.writeBytes(getPOSTParameters);
        writeRequest.flush();
        writeRequest.close();

        //To get the Response Codes
        int responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
        logger.debug("\nSending 'POST' request to URL::" +url);
        logger.debug("Post parameters ::"+getPOSTParameters);
        logger.debug("Response Code ::" + responseCode);

        //parse the response
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        while((getResponseline = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            builder.append(getResponseline);
            builder.append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        getPOSTResponse = builder.toString();
        //logger.debug("\n "+getPOSTResponse);

        //Disconnect the connection
        urlConn.disconnect();

    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.error("\n"+ioe);
    }
    return getPOSTResponse;
}
```

can anyone suggest how to decode the response?

Comment: Get the charset from the response content type header instead of defaulting to ut-8.

Comment: Musa,can you point me to some examples of how to get charset from the response content type header,ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `InputStreamReader`,I would suggest to use [InflaterInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html) class,which can be used to uncompress data.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
InflaterInputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream()), new Inflater(true));

int i;  
while((i=in.read())!=-1){  
   builder.append(i);    
} 

getPOSTResponse = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Hi RE350, i tried your suggestion and now im getting a null response

Comment: i tried using, InflaterInputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream(),new Inflater(true)); it gives null by throwing exception as::java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type

Answer (score 0):

I 've had the same problem too and I removed all request properties except `Content-Type`, and now it is working.

Donno how/why it works now.